# Managing ServerCore 2008 R2 in DMZ

Tags: dmz, windows-server-core, windows

I am looking to replace our DMZ servers with Server Core editions but am struggling with remote management.  The computers in the DMZ are in a workgroup while the client I am connecting from is on our domain.  Whenever I load an MMC or Server Manager I get countless "Access Denied" warnings or Kerberos errors.  It looks like Server Manager is trying to append the domain to the end of the computer name as well.

Is there anyway to manage a workgroup server core installation from a domain member computer?  As it is a VM we can always access the console but would like to make use of RSAT tools as much as possible.  I can RDP to the box as well.  I can't quite seem to find the answer I am looking for anywhere thus far.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable the Windows Remote Management service (WinRM) it allows you to remotely execute PowerShell commands on the server. Most operations that can be completed in Server Manager have an equivalent PowerShell cmdlet.

Helpful links:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384372(v=vs.85).aspx